# R how to bin weighted data

Tags: r, binning

Hi I'm trying to draw an histogram in ggplot but my data doesn't have all the values but values and number of occurrences.

```
value=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
weight<-c(8976,10857,10770,14075,18075,20757,24770,14556,11235,8042)
df <- data.frame(value,weight)
df
   value weight
1      1   8976
2      2  10857
3      3  10770
4      4  14075
5      5  18075
6      6  20757
7      7  24770
8      8  14556
9      9  11235
10    10   8042
```

Anybody would know either how to bin the values or how to plot an histogram of binned values.
I want to get something that would look like

```
    bin  weight
1   1-2   19833
2   3-4   24845
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one method for binning the data up:

```
df$bin <- findInterval(df$value,seq(1,max(df$value),2))
result <- aggregate(df["weight"],df["bin"],sum)
# get your named bins automatically without specifying them individually
result$bin <- tapply(df$value,df$bin,function(x) paste0(x,collapse="-"))

# result
   bin weight
1  1-2  19833
2  3-4  24845
3  5-6  38832
4  7-8  39326
5 9-10  19277

# barplot it (base example since Roman has covered ggplot)
with(result,barplot(weight,names.arg=bin))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would add another variable that designates the binning and then

```
df$group <- rep(c("1-2", "3-4", "5-6", "7-8", "9-10"), each = 2)
```

draw it using ggplot.

```
ggplot(df, aes(y = weight, x = group)) + stat_summary(fun.y="sum", geom="bar")
```

[image]

Comment: Better to use a factor: `cut(..., breaks=..., labels=...)`

Answer (score 0):

Just expand your data:

```
value=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
weight<-c(8976,10857,10770,14075,18075,20757,24770,14556,11235,8042)
dat = rep(value,weight)
# plot result
histres = hist(dat)
```

And histres contains some potentially useful information if you want details of the histogram data.